# Java - A JPQL Query to delete a oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence, jpql

If I have this 3 entities :

> @Entity 
>   public class Student {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> protected Long id;
>
> private String name;
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Entity
>   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
>   public class Course {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> protected Long id;
>
> @OneToMany
> private List<Student> students;
>
> private String name;
> ```
>
> }
>
> @Entity
>   @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
>   public class Group {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
> protected Long id;
>
> @OneToMany
> private List<Student> students;
>
> private String name;
> ```
>
> }

How can I delete students with a JPQL query ?

I try

> DELETE FROM Student s 
>   WHERE s.name = "John Doe"

But I have

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`, CONSTRAINT `FK_course_student_students_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`students_ID`) REFERENCES `student` (`ID`))

I need to do this in pure JPQL for performance, I can't do an entity.remove, because I have 10000 John doe and I need to delete them in a second.

Why JPQL doesn't say : "Hey, let's remove this john doe from this biology course, he doesn't exist" instead of "Hey, the biology course is so important that no student can be remove from this course ! "

What I am missing and what sort of annotation I have to use ?

Thanks !

Edit : Add a @JoinColumn to the OnToMany relationship could work, unless the students are referenced by different tables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default unidirectional one-to-many relationship is mapped via join table. If you don't have any special requirements about using join talbe you can use foreign key in `Student` instead, it can be configured as follows:

```
@OneToMany 
@JoinColumn
private List<Student> students;
```

It also should solve your problem with constrain violation.

Comment: Thanks, it resovle the problem for the original question, but I have another problem now, I have in fact multiple tables referencing the Student entity, so Student couldn't store the relationship, I need the multiple relathionship table.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can clear the references to the objects being deleted in a deleted all using an update all query.

You can also configure you constraint on the database to cascade or null on delete to avoid constraint issues.